# Layout problem on favorites tab of user profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, watched-tags

[image: Screenshot]
[**Click to embiggen**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwfzU.png)

Confirmed in:

- Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
- Chromium 12.0.712.0 for Windows 7
- Opera 11.10 for Windows 7
- Internet Explorer 9.0.8112.16421
- Internet Explorer 8.0.6001.18702 on Windows XP
- Safari 5.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.6.7
- Chrome 10.0.648.204 on Mac OS X 10.6.7
- MobileSafari on iOS 4.3.2/iPad

Works as expected in:

- [Links 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XudD3.png)
- [Lynx 2.8.7rel.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/He7st.png)
- MobileSafari iPhone

Comment: i'm looking into this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix will be in the next deployment.